# Intercepting ClassLoader.getResource(String) calls, with a custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

We're trying to debug an unreproducible issue with WebStart, where access to resources inside Jars will "randomly" fail. Maybe one every 1000 application run will end with this error, which can happen anywhere where resources are read from a jar.

Searching in Google and the Java Bug database brought nothing similar (or at least, nothing helpful).

We are trying to get more info into what happens on the client by "instrumenting" the application so we track all calls to `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` (including indirectly over `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)`). Without changing the app code, I have created a "launcher" that would run the whole app with a custom classloader.

Unfortunately, it seems my ClassLoader is somehow bypassed. I do not see any of the expected System.out output. Here is what I tried:

```
private static final class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private MyClassLoader() {
        super(TheClassThatMainIsIn.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public URL getResource(String name) {
        System.out.println("getResource("+name+")");
        // Snip
        return super.getResource(name);
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        System.out.println("getResourceAsStream("+name+")");
        final URL url = getResource(name);
        try {
            return url != null ? url.openStream() : null;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting MyRealApp Launcher ...");
    final MyClassLoader loader = new MyClassLoader();
    try {
        Class<?> realAppClasss = loader.loadClass("MyRealAppClass");
        Method main = realAppClasss.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        main.invoke(null, (Object) args);
    } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (final Error e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
        final Throwable cause = e.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) cause;
        }
        if (cause instanceof Error) {
            throw (Error) cause;
        }
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(cause);
    } catch (final Throwable t) {
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
    }
}
```

*What am I doing wrong here?*

Comment: Are you overriding findClass() and loadClassData?

Comment: No, I'm not overriding those; I'm not interested in "classes"; just "resources". Should I? If so, what should I do beyond just passing the call to the base-class?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to.  I misunderstood your question the first time I read it.  What you're doing seems correct.  I would suggest including the ClassLoader source code in your project stepping through this with a debugger to see why it's not calling your overridden method.

Comment: CL in Java works on a delegation strategy. Before loading the class the CL asks his parent if the byte definition for class X is already known. Only if no ancestor knew the class bytes then the actual CL is loading the class definition. In your case it seems that `MyRealAppClass` was loaded on application startup and therefore the `loadClass` call was delegated to the system CL which also takes care of the resource-loading as already pointed out by @Gamlor - You can try  [`-verbose:class`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtm) and see if it was loaded before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This works, in principal.

However, you've to account how the resource loading code get's to the class loader. Since the class don't show up, it looks like they use the parents class loader.
You've to account different scenarios:

Code using context class loader, like:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("via-context");
```

This is easy to achieve, by setting it before calling into main:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
Method main = realAppClasss.getMethod("main", String[].class);
main.invoke(null, (Object) args);
```

Next thing you've to account is code which 'takes' class loader from current class, and load it that. When you're class is loaded via the parent class loader, it will also use that class loader to get the resource. Like:

```
MyRealAppClass.class.getResource("via-class");
MyRealAppClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("via-class");
objectInfApp.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("via-class");
```

To avoid that you've to ensure that the apps classes are actually loaded with your class loader, not the parent. For a simple main, you can extend from the URL class loader, skip any parent and user the original class path for the URL's. Like:

```
// URL class loader to lookup in jars etc
private static class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader
{
    public MyClassLoader(URL[] urls) {
        // Use the given URLs and skip any parent class loader, directly go to the system loader
        super(urls,null);
    }

// ...

// Then setup the class path
    String[] classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(";");
    URL[] classPathUrls = new URL[classPath.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < classPath.length; i++) {
        classPathUrls[i] = new File(classPath[i]).toURL();

    }
    MyClassLoader loader = new MyClassLoader(classPathUrls);
```

This should cover the most basic cases. When you're actual application itself has more class loader trickery, there might more you need to setup.